# Present simple or Past simple

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Can you tell me which of following sentence is correct and please explain to me.

I meet a person who has been a programmer for 2 years and ask

1. Why do you want to be a programmer?
2. Why did you want to be a programmer?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences are correct, but they ask slightly different things

> Why **do** you want to be a programmer?
>   *What are your reasons to* ***continue*** *to being a programmer?*

can also be used for "Why do you want to *become* a programmer?" if the person never programmed before.

> Why **did** you want to be a programmer?
>   *Why did you want to* ***become*** *a programmer?*